# ayuda con usar CONCAT en php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo una consulta y quiero que en la interfaz el ID me lo de con el ID y nombre y estoy usando este codigo

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$paginaActual = $_POST['partida'];

$nroProductos = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reporte"));
$nroLotes = 10;
$nroPaginas = ceil($nroProductos/$nroLotes);
$lista = '';
$tabla = '';

if($paginaActual > 1){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual-1).');">Anterior</a></li>';
}
for($i=1; $i<=$nroPaginas; $i++){
    if($i == $paginaActual){
        $lista = $lista.'<li class=""><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }else{
        $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
}
if($paginaActual < $nroPaginas){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual+1).');">Siguiente</a></li>';
}

if($paginaActual <= 1){
    $limit = 0;
}else{
    $limit = $nroLotes*($paginaActual-1);
}

$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reporte LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes ");


$tabla = $tabla.'<table class="table table-bordered table-inverse">
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                      <th width="150">emergencia</th>
                        <th width="150">descripcion emergencia</th>
                        <th width="200">nombre del reportante</th>
                        <th width="150">telefono</th>
                        <th width="150">ubicacion</th>
                        <th width="150">nivel de la emergencia</th>
                         <th width="150">opciones</th>

                    </tr>';

while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
    $tabla = $tabla.'<tr>
    <td>'.$registro2['nombre'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$registro2['desc_emergencia'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$registro2['nombre_reportante'].'</td>
                        <td> '.$registro2['telefono_reportante'].'</td>
                        <td> '.$registro2['ubicacion'].'</td>

                                <td> '.$registro2['nivel_emergencia'].'</td>

                        <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id'].');" class="glyphicon-pencil"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
                      </tr>';       
}


$tabla = $tabla.'</table>';



$array = array(0 => $tabla,
               1 => $lista);

echo json_encode($array);
```

?>

donde uso el concat para que en mi interfaz me de el ID como ID y nombre juntos? saludos.

Comment: quieres que `$registro2['nombre']`vaya junto con el ID ? en la tabla ?

Comment: si bro, algo parecido a este ejemplo select concat(iniciales,id) codigo,firstname nombre, login, passwd, fecha from operador;

Comment: Creo q hay una diferencia con lo q preguntas y comentas,lo que quieres hacer es asignar a `id el concat(id,' ',nombre) `y ese id usarlo por ejemplo en  `editarProducto('.$registro2['id'].') ` o en el nombre y mostrarlo en el td?ademas el codigo sin el concat asi como lo posteas funciona?

Answer (score 4):

Bueno,

En tu consulta agregaría la funcion `CONCAT_WS` de mysql.
Quedaría así.

`$registro = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', id, nombre) as codigo, * FROM reporte LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes ");`

Donde el primer parametro el el string separador entre los campos seleccionados.

Despues en PHP lo obtienes como:

```
while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
    $tabla = $tabla.'<tr>
            <td>'.$registro2['campoconcatenado'].'</td>
            <td>'.$registro2['nombre'].'</td>
            <td>'.$registro2['desc_emergencia'].'</td>
            <td>'.$registro2['nombre_reportante'].'</td>
            <td> '.$registro2['telefono_reportante'].'</td>
            <td> '.$registro2['ubicacion'].'</td>
            <td> '.$registro2['nivel_emergencia'].'</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id'].');" class="glyphicon-pencil"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
            </tr>';       
}
```

En cuanto a PHP

Solo bastaría concatenar los dos string de esta manera, en el caso que lo quieras separar por algun string, sino omite el `""`

`$registro2['id']."".$registro2['nombre']`

Espero te sirva, me cuentas
Saludos,

Comment: no me funciono :( me podrias parar un correo para mandarte mi proyecto para que me lo cheques?

Comment: claro jolsalazar // gmail